# access relational data from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access a single value which is comming from entity relational database table. I am passing it to viewbag but due to wrong syntax its not working on viewbag inside my mvc view. Please see picture then you will know i am getting value of sub relational table properly.

[image: picture]

Controller:
public ActionResult ProductEdit(int id)

```
{
        using (BlexzWebDbEntities db = new BlexzWebDbEntities())
        {
            ViewBag.Product = db.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

MVC View:

```
Category: @ViewBag.Product.Categories.CategoryName <br />
```

Comment: In the screen shot it looks like the property is named `Category`, but you're trying to access a property called `Categories`.  Just a typo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code you can directly pass value to your viewbag

```
 var Data = db.Products.Where(x=>x.ProductId == id).FirstOrDefault();
  ViewBag.Product= Data.Categories.CategoryName;
```

in your view

```
 Category: @ViewBag.Product <br />
```